# Can I get an updated ISO with all the updates already applied?

Tags: release-management

I'm going to install Ubuntu on my other PC, but the thing is that after installing Ubuntu it's going to update more than 208 MB and I don't want to update 208 MB after installation.
Is there any way that I can download an already-updated Ubuntu 11.10 ISO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the LTS releases get point release updates, so no, you can't get an already updated 11.10 image.

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OfflineUpdateSpec

follow this link to reach a web page describing 3 main options available for solving your problem.

Comment: This seems more like a page for developers trying to create such a method.

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be to use AptonCd as described in the link above. You would need to build your "master" system with the packages and updates that you want. You would then use AptonCd to create a backup of your packages and save them to some storage medium. You would then use the 11.10 ISO to install the base version of Oneric and then install AptOnCD and do a restore from the backup that you made. Packages should be restored to /var/cache/apt/archives. You would then need to run:

`sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb`

Take a nice Starbucks break and then come back in an hour or two and it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

There are three options to download the packages only once:

1) Use the 11.10 CD and refuse to update. This will give you 11.10 pre-updates, and is best if your network connection is slow or flaky.

2) Use a pre-release 12.04 build. This is not recommended if you are unwilling to put up with the very likely breakage in pre-release software.

3) Use the Minimal Install ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD ) or NetInstall 11.10 options. This will give you a current 11.10, and will reduce your total download considerably, though the total install time may not be shorter. You need a reliable network connection for this to work.

Comment: I'd heavily recommend against option 2 personally. You will not end up with the same package versions as an updated 11.10 would have, and as noted you'll likely have to deal with an unstable system frequently. I'm a 12.04 Alpha 1 tester and I can vouch that despite the similarities in appearance, a pre-release 12.04 is not really the same thing as 11.10 kept up to date.