# Updated ISO with all the updates already applied for LTS release?

Tags: updates, iso

I need to get an Ubuntu ISO in which the updates are already applied so that I wont have to install the updates immediately after the installation.

(The latest ISO is unbootable in my Dell machine 
Question (https://askubuntu.com/questions/507097) 
and I just want to check if an updated iso can do anything better)

This question is similar to
[Can I get an updated ISO with all the updates already applied?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85624/can-i-get-an-updated-iso-with-all-the-updates-already-applied)

The answer hints that an updated ISO may be available for an LTS release. How to get this?

I tried updating my persistant live usb image from update manager. But due to some reason or other, some updates are failing and the usb ends up unbootable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/  and download the **14.04.1** version 
applicable to you. 
Its the Latest version of Trusty Tahr with all the bugs fixed and patched till this July.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect timing for question, official ISO had been updated a week ago. Or there is an official network installer ISO, that downloads all packages from net during installation. 
That said, the only thing that can help you with new version is kernel.

Comment: So I should have been trying with the latest kernels. So is it possible to downgrade the kernel to a previous version in a downloaded ISO? How can I achieve the solution mentioned in the first answer of this post?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/457658/ubuntu-14-04-lts-screen-is-flickering-on-dell-optiplex-9010-aio-system